# How to remove an ad using userscript?

Tags: javascript, ads, userscripts

I am trying to remove ads on a website in userscript, but `.remove()` and `style.display="none"` doesn't seem to work.

My code so far:

```js
var adTop = document.getElementsByName('abp leaderboard-abp')[0];
adTop.style.display="none";

var adBt = document.querySelectorAll('.profile-ads-container')[0];
adBt.style.display="none";

var adLeft = document.querySelectorAll('.abp abp-container left-abp')[0];
adLeft.style.display="none";

var adRight = document.querySelectorAll('.abp abp-container right-abp')[0];
adRight.style.display="none";
```

---

If anything else is wrong with my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to select ads elements but you apply changes only to the first ad element using the `[0]`

you can instead select and loop over all of them to assign the required behavior or style.

for example :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.abp leaderboard-abp').forEach((elem) => {
     elem.style.display = 'none';
});
```

** If this didn't work for you please provide a sample of the HTML you are working on.